Unity Xcode iOS / Why is Unity Ads and mediation an Pod in my project?
I want to publish my Unity game to iOS, but when I tried to archive it in Xcode, I got this error:

Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS $_UnityAds

Other Projects of mine don't have this problem. So this seems to be a problem with my Unity project.
I don't want to use UnityAds.
When I have a look at the pods, there is one pod called "UnityAds" and some "Unity Mediation...." pods.

Could this pods be the problem?
What determines which pods are displayed and required here?
How can I remove these dependencies on Unity Ads and mediation?
I have already completely removed Unity Ads from the project.
